# Image has to fit in div without losing proportions

Tags: jquery, css, slider

I've made a simple slider, that works perfectly, but I can't get the image fit in the div without losing proportion. It must be quite simple but I can't get it right.

Can you help with it?

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/DCDcp/) is the code

Many thanks in advance.

```
#featuredslider{
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-bottom:80px;
    width:1080px;
    height: 350px;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    top:85px;
}
#featuredslider img{
    position:absolute;
    width:100%; 
    height:auto;
    max-height:350px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of defining `width: 100%;` make it `max-width: 100%;`

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/DCDcp/1/)

Same way, you can use `max-height` property as well, but if you want that your `img` should stretch `100%` wide, than your `img` will stretch.

Comment: Ok thanks! I tried it but it won't fill the full 1080px. The width in this case is more important than height (although this must be within 350px)

Comment: @Jssonline Sorry, was out of Internet connection, I had typed this comment for you "obviously it won't, you need to make it responsive just like [Nivo Slider](http://dev7studios.com/nivo-slider/)" and you welcome :)

Comment: No problem! When the problem was solved it became also clear to make it responsive. The site is done and delivered! Many thanks again.